How to find the space taken by the rotation of a 3d object to place another copy right besides it to make a fence in an irregular terrain
I am trying to create a fence over an irregular terrain, if the fence object is not rotated, it fits one besides another, but when i rotate them to fit the terrain irregularities, thew don't fit one beside the other when the previous object was rotated too much, so i deducted that the bigger the rotations is the biggest the gasp between them, i want to know how to find the space taken by the rotation to fit the nest fence besides the previous one without gaps.Thanks in advance, i am not a math guy at all.
I don't know what to do to fix that.

Can't you just place the fence tiles next to each other without a gap and without rotation and if anything account only for the elevation?

I didn't understand your question, my current algorithm places the fences correctly one beside another when no elevation is present in surface. When there is elevation, i rotate it to fit it but the a gasp is created between the current and next fence.

I think a picture with a few examples would go a long way in better describing this. Some code of how the rotation works would be helpful. BUT, theoretically, I think your issue is that you are calculating the distance using straight distances, not accounting for the terrain. it's like using aerial distance in a city, it's useless. You need to account for the terrain in the distance calculation. BUT again, that's just how I picture you were doing it. You need to post images and code for us to be able to figure this out. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

A fence consists of "rails". Usually 2. Or 1 or 3. The rails are lines in 3D space with 2 x,y,z endpoints. It's easier to make a fence by connecting end points in 3D space instead of connecting, and then rotating the "elevation" (which will always result in a gap). I use the same technique for "route marching" (follow the leader) over contoured maps.

Here is an example of my algorithm result:

The algorithm to get the correct rotation is a raycast to the edge of the fence and get the vector of the terrain elevation from the pivot point of the fence (left bottom side of mesh) to the end of the mesh.

This is no answer. Add the information to your question instead.
